# sql query in listview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

Hi I want to execute this two queries and display the results at the same time in list view.How can i execute this query in one select command:

My sql queries:

```
Shareholder details:
   Select inlt_parentcompanyid,inlt_effectinterest,inlt_sharetype,inlt_shares from InterestLogTable where inlt_childcompid=5
    Subsidiary details:
    select inlt_childcompid,inlt_effectinterest,inlt_sharetype,inlt_shares from InterestLogTable where inlt_parentcompanyid =5
```

My asp.net list view:

```
Shareholder details:
                    <td><%#Eval("owner_parentCompanyId")%>&nbsp;</td> 
                    <td><%#Eval("owner_sharetype")%>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><%#Eval("owner_effectinterest")%>&nbsp;</td>   
                    <td><%#Eval("owner_deemedinterest")%>&nbsp;</td>                 
                    <td><%#Eval("owner_shares")%>&nbsp;</td> 

Sunsidiary details:
                    <td><%#Eval("owner_childCompanyId")%>&nbsp;</td> 
                    <td><%#Eval("owner_sharetype")%>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><%#Eval("owner_effectinterest")%>&nbsp;</td>   
                    <td><%#Eval("owner_deemedinterest")%>&nbsp;</td>                 
                    <td><%#Eval("owner_shares")%>&nbsp;</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use it in the same listview your query should return a singl result set with the columns from two tables. For that you have to inner join. like this

```
 Select inlt_parentcompanyid,inlt_effectinterest,inlt_sharetype,inlt_shares,inlt_childcompid,inlt_effectinterest,inlt_sharetype,inlt_shares from InterestLogTable INNER JOIN InterestLogTable ON InterestLogTable.intl_parentcompanyid=InterestLogTable.inlt_parentcompanyid where
```

InterestLogTable.intl_parentcompanyid=5

Of course you need to take care of columns names which are same in both the tables by using tableName.coulumnName